# Can Stack Overflow handle heaps of questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I don't think Stack Overflow can handle as many questions as pop up per second. Before I started using Stack Overflow, if I asked one question there were many people answering for me and I could choose the best answer. But now some questions can't even get 10 views or 20 views.

What needs to be done to get more attention for a question and to get an answer?

Comment: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Ask a good question with a good title.

Comment: Still doing better than most Q&A sites with answer rates so bad they don't publish them

Comment: I think the active members, many of them active since the very beginning, got fed up with trivial request for help and/or low quality question so they are now more picky. If in the past they used to check every question and give it a chance now they first look in the title and tags and if there's good chance of low quality or irrelevant stuff they won't even read the question. Nothing official, this is just my feeling which explains the situation you describe.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I agree.  Also, because of the sheer number of questions on Stack Overflow, I just look at the Top Questions now.  The last time I tried to look at the newest questions, more than 15 newer questions would be asked in the time it would take me to read 15 questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

Stack Overflow handles heaps of questions. Just ask a simple question.

Go through following posts:

1. [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question).
2. [Is it getting harder to ask good questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45955/is-it-getting-harder-to-ask-good-questions)
3. [Can I draw attention to a well deserving answer on my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114839/can-i-draw-attention-to-a-well-deserving-answer-on-my-question)
4. [What should I do with a question that I can't get an answer for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108901/what-should-i-do-with-a-question-that-i-cant-get-an-answer-for)
5. [Do easier questions get more activity than harder questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96584/do-easier-questions-get-more-activity-than-harder-questions)
6. [How to get answers to unintuitive questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90364/how-to-get-answers-to-unintuitive-questions)

Message from [Guru Jon Skeet for Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Still not got attention then:

## Go for Bounty